# word interop onpreviewclosed event

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

Scenario:
Existing winforms application with embedded word using dsoframer

Problem:
When user hits preview and exits preview, the fields are showing the codes like '{FORMTEXT}' instead of the actual values. When I click on print options on print preview, the 'Show field codes instead of their values' option is disabled. Don't know why.

I am looking to achieve previewclosed event so I can iterate through the fields and set the field.ShowCodes to false.

Answer (score 0):

The print options are not relevant to what the user sees when print preview exits. Word has no event that triggers for print preview. But you don't need to iterate through the fields to ensure that field codes are not displaying. Use:

```
Document.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there a way to override the functionality of the preview exit? Then you can send a callback before you exit the preview.